# Dgrid - Display label for number (i.e. 02 = Cat) I want to display Cat - not the number

Tags: javascript, database, dojo, dgrid

In my Dgrid I have a column that displays the code (in number format) for an event.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UwGR.png)

I want to display the label not the number in the dgrid. So if 1 = Cat. In the database it shows as a 1 - but I want to display 'Cat' in dgrid. Can't find anything on how to do this.

Help or a lead in a direction would be helpful. Thanks!!

UPDATED: 6.16.15

Here is the code. I'm limited in what I can show. [image]

These are some of the codes. 02 = XXXXX, 03 = XXXXX1, and so on and so on. Right now, the dgrid displays the numbers. It's kind of like a key. I need it to display what the number represents in the dgrid, not the number. So 02 should display 'Traffic Stop'. Not sure how to do a jsfiddle yet, and don't have a whole lot of extra time at the moment. I'm limited in what info I can give out, so I'd have to recreate a dummy version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>XXXXXXXX Events</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/web_ui/dgrid/css/skins/slate.css">

<h1>XXXXXXXX Events</h1>

<form id="queryForm">
        <label for="XXXXXField">XXXXX Type contains:</label>
        <input id="XXXXXField" name="event_type">
        <button type="submit">Filter</button>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    </form>


    <script src="/static/web_ui/dojo/dojo.js"
        data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>

    <script>
        require([
            'dojo/_base/declare',
            'dojo/dom',
            'dojo/on',
            'dstore/Rest',
            'dstore/Request',
            'dgrid/extensions/ColumnResizer',
            'dgrid/extensions/ColumnReorder',
            'dgrid/CellSelection',
            'dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry',
        //  'dstore/Memory',
        //  'dstore/Trackable',
        //   'dstore/Cache',
            'dgrid/OnDemandGrid'
        //  'dojo/domReady!'
], function (declare, dom, on, Rest, Request, ColumnResizer, ColumnReorder, CellSelection, DijitRegistry, OnDemandGrid) {
        var store = new Rest({target:'/api/XXXXXXEvents/?format=json',
            sortParam: 'ordering', ascendingPrefix:'', descendingPrefix:'-'
    });


    //  var cacheStore = Cache.create(store, {
    //      cachedStore: new (Memory.createSubclass(Trackable)) ()
    //  });

        var grid = window.grid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, ColumnResizer, ColumnReorder, CellSelection, DijitRegistry])) ({
        collection: store,
        selectionMode: 'single',
        sort: 'id',
    //    idProperty: 'id',

        columns: [
            {field: 'id', label:'ID', resizeable: false},
            {field: 'XXXXX_type', label:'XXXXX Type', resizeable: false},
            {field: 'XXXXX_at', label:'XXXXX Time', resizeable: false},
            {field:'XXXXX', label:'XXXXX Count', resizeable: false},
            {field:'XXXXX', label:'XXXXX', resizeable: false},
            {field:'XXXXX_info', label:'XXXXX Info', resizeable: false},
            {field:'hidden', label:'Hidden', resizeable: false},
            {field:'XXXXX', label:'XXXXX', resizeable: false},
            {field:'XXXXX', label:'XXXXX', resizeable: false}
        ]

    }, 'grid');

 grid.startup();    

    on(dom.byId('queryForm'), 'submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                grid.set('collection', store.filter({
                    // Pass a RegExp to Memory's filter method
                    // Note: this code does not go out of its way to escape
                    // characters that have special meaning in RegExps
                    last: new RegExp("^\d+$")
                }));
            });

            on(dom.byId('queryForm'), 'reset', function() {
                // Reset the query when the form is reset
                grid.set('collection', store);
            });

    });

    </script>

</head>

 <body class="slate">
<div id="grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please share some relevant code and share jsfiddle if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the column formatter function for rendering data.

check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/8tLwpcw0/) over here.

Check the examples over [here](http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/)

I have taken [this](http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/Grid_rendering.html) example and modified as per your needs.

```
require([
    'dgrid/Grid',
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function(Grid) {
    var data = [

        { id: 1, number: 7 },
        { id: 2, number: 8 },
        { id: 3, number: 9 }
    ];

    function testFormatter(item){
                //console.log(item,typeof(item));
                var newItem;
                if ( item == 7 ) 
                    newItem = 'Dog'
                else if ( item == 8 )
                    newItem = 'Cat'
                 else if ( item == 9 )
                    newItem = 'Bird'
         return newItem;

    }

    var columnsFormatter = [
                {
                    label: "Number",
                    field: "number",
                    formatter: testFormatter
                }
            ];

    var grid = new Grid({
        columns: columnsFormatter
    }, "gridcontainer");;
    grid.renderArray(data);
});
```

Comment: It would generally be more appropriate to use the `get` function for this type of transformation, rather than `formatter`; in this case, you could swap it in for `formatter` with no other changes. The benefit of this is avoiding potential for XSS, since formatter functions' return values are treated as HTML fragments.  Meanwhile, note that sort is unaffected by either `get` or `formatter` since it takes place after the store request, so if you want sorting to work with the transformed values, you'd have to do it on the store end.

Comment: I'll do that! Thank you!!